# multiple parameters in wmic path win32_process get

Tags: windows, powershell, wmic

I want to run this command `wmic path Win32_Process get ParentProcessId, commandLine, creationdate, executablepath, name, processId` with several parameters,but powershell swear at the syntax if I try to write comma-separated. What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the [wmi](/questions/tagged/wmi)/[cim](/questions/tagged/cim) cmdlets give you all the properties of a class on the object you receive, so you do not need to specify each one:

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process
$wmi | Get-Member -MemberType Property

$props = 'ParentProcessId', 'CommandLine', 'CreationDate', 'ExecutablePath', 'Name', 'ProcessId'
$wmi | Select-Object -Property $props
```

As a best practice: if [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) gives you a native abstraction (in this case, `Get-WmiObject` or `Get-CimInstance`), you should use it!

Comment: I use ucmdb. I had to play some commands for verification. This command was written in the version that is contained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Commas indicate arrays.  If you really want to wmic, you can use the magical "stop parsing" operator:

```
wmic --% path Win32_Process get ParentProcessId, commandLine, creationdate, executablepath, name, processId
```

Get-wmiobject or get-ciminstance will output objects though, that are easier to manipulate.  Get-ciminstance even has tab completion on the classnames, and piping to select-object or where-object, you get tab completion on the properties.

```
get-ciminstance win32_process | select parentprocessId, commandLine, creationdate, executablepath, name, processId
get-ciminstance win32_process | where commandline -match chrome
```